# Use javascript to change text only in an element

Tags: javascript, html, text, replace

Is there a simple way to change the text of an element only using vanilla javascript? In the code below, I thought that using `.textContent`, rather than `.innerHTML` would change the text and leave the image behind.

```
<head>
    <script>
        function change_stuff() {
            var div = document.getElementById('to_change');
            div.textContent = "OMG...it's an image!";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="to_change">
        This is a huge block of text that I want to replace while leaving the image in place
        <img src="./the_image.jpg">
    </div>
    <button onclick="change_stuff();">
        ThE dOER!!
    </button>
</body>
```

I've also tried but had little to no success with many variations of this:

```
function change_stuff() {
    var div = document.getElementById('to_change');
    var text = div.textContent;

    div.textContent = text.replace(text, "");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Get the first textNode by [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) property and update the content.

```js
function change_stuff() {
  // get the first child node, in your code which is the text node
  var t = document.getElementById('to_change').firstChild;

  // update the text contents in the node
  t.nodeValue = "";

  // or t.textContent = "";

  // or remove the node itself
  // t.parentNode.removeChild(t)
}
```

```html
<div id="to_change">
  This is a huge block of text that I want to replace while leaving the image in place
  <img src="./the_image.jpg">
</div>
<button onclick="change_stuff();">
  ThE dOER!!
</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

In the **[W3C DOM (Document Object Model)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)**, ***everything*** is a "node". Nodes come in **[different types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)** (comment nodes, element nodes, attribute nodes and even text nodes). It may seem counter-intuitive that an element like `div` that doesn't have any nested elements that can contain text inside it actually does implicitly have a child element within it that contains the raw text and that element is a text node.

In order to access that (which will be separate from other elements within the `div`, you can navigate to the `div` and look for (in this case, it's **[`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)** because the text comes first and the image is second.

Also, when it comes to replacing the original text with something else...You were trying to call the `.replace()` string function on the `div` and not the text within the `div`. You can isolate just the text of the `div` by navigating to the text node within it and working just on that.

```js
function change_stuff() {
  // Get a reference to the div element's text node which is a child node
  // of the div.
  var divText = document.getElementById('to_change').firstChild;
  
  // Get the current text within the element:
  var text = divText.textContent;

  // You can do whatever you want with the text (in this case replace)
  // but you must assign the result back to the element
  divText.textContent = text.replace(text, "");
}
```

```html
<div id="to_change">
        This is a huge block of text that I want to replace while leaving the image in place
        <img src="./the_image.jpg">
</div>
<button onclick="change_stuff();">
        ThE dOER!!
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or the pragmatic:

```js
function change_stuff() {
  var div = document.getElementById('to_change'),
    img = div.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  div.innerHTML = "OMG...it's an image!";
  div.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<div id="to_change">
  This is a huge block of text that I want to replace while leaving the image in place
  <img src="./the_image.jpg">
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="change_stuff();">
  ThE dOER!!
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **innerText** to set the text within the div (i.e.: `div.innerText = replacement`).

See [Node.textContent - Differences from innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText).